# Ideas on how to animate multiple bezier curves?

Tags: bezier, html5-animation

I am trying to create a drawing animation out of a picture that is quite similar to [this one](http://image.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/52034/52034,1132003776,10/stock-vector-multiple-colour-bezier-curve-line-wave-vector-725224.jpg).

From what I've been researching, I think my goal is to make multiple bezier curves. The problem is, since I do mostly programming but not quite so on the graphic design part, this gives me quite a headache.

So, any advice on where should I start (e.g. software I should use, etc.)? Thanks before.

P.S: in the end, the animation will be put on a web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Coding Math](http://www.codingmath.com/) is a great resource, assuming you have basic knowledge of HTML, CSS and JavaScript.